# Calendar(DaysofWeek) in qml

Tags: qt, qml

How to display only 2 characters for DaysOfWeek in qml calendar i.e. Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa ?

Is there any property available to display only 2 characters?*

As far as i know below mentioned properties are available:
model.longName : string The long version of the day name; for example, "Monday" (QLocale::LongFormat)
model.shortName : string    The short version of the day name; for example, "Mon" (QLocale::ShortFormat)
model.narrowName : string   A special version of the day name for use when space is limited; for example, "M" (QLocale::NarrowFormat)

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: DayOfWeekRow {  width: 16.65625 ; height: 18

                        delegate: Text {
                            text: model.shortName
                    }   //In place of shortName i want to display only 2 character for DaysOfWeek

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in method to get the output you're looking for. But you can do it yourself by just mapping the existing names to your preferred names.

```
property var dayNames: { "Sunday" : "Su", "Monday" : "Mo", ... }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
property string longName: Qt.formatDate(new Date(), "dddd")  // "Sunday"
property string shortName: dayNames[longName]  // "Su"
```